# Replacing Type1 fonts in PDF with TrueType1 fonts

Tags: pdf, embedded-fonts, truetype-fonts

I have an old PDF with Type1 fonts. I can't copy paste text from this PDF - there are no copyright issues, this is simply some old document - not even sure how it was created.

How do I replace these with truetype fonts?

Comment: For what purpose? Replacing the font won't allow you to copy text to the clipboard.

Comment: If the ability to copy has been disabled, the ability to edit the PDF file will surely be disabled as well. Check in `File > Properties` in `Adobe Reader`.

Comment: @MikeF - Purpose, is to copy and paste in a Word document pieces of the pdf for quoting in an article. 
@paradroid - All restrictions - printing, copying, etc are allowed as Allowed.

Comment: Disabled copy/paste is a security setting unrelated to the font. Replacing the font in the PDF won't solve your problem. @Linker3000's solution may work, depending on how LibreOffice respects PDF security settings.

Answer (score 0):

**LibreOffice**  http://www.libreoffice.org/download/ supports opening PDFs in its draw app. Once loaded you may be able to select what you want as text blocks. Worth a try as it's a free download.

Comment: thanks, I have 20 docs spanning over 700 pages, that is the challenge. So, I do need something that will work in a semi-automated fashion.